# undefined method for true:TrueClass error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

undefined method `start_date' for true:TrueClass error for the following controller action:

```
@payment = Payment.find(params[:payment_id])
@invoice = @payment.invoice # returns true instead of the invoice object
@start_date = @invoice.start_date.to_time.beginning_of_month # error on method start_date, since @invoice is returning true
```

When I run the same code in console:

```
Payment.find(58)
#<Payment id: 58, amount: 1000.0, method: "1", invoice_id: 13, job_id: 1, client_id: 6, notes: "111111", date_received: "2014-03-17", number: "1111", created_at: "2014-03-18 03:42:33", updated_at: "2014-03-18 03:42:33", order_id: nil>

Payment.find(58).invoice
  Payment Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 58]]
 => true
```

It seems like the SQL query is constructed improperly.

Model associations

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
end
```

Comment: make sure that you don't have a method or column called `invoice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old method defined in the payment model was being run instead of the belongs_to, has_many relationship methods.

Removal of the following code fixed the issue.

```
def invoice
  if self.invoice_id
    return true
  end
end
```